# Question about exporting data from Google Analytics to BigQuery events_intraday_

Tags: google-bigquery

I have question regarding our data export from Google Analytics to BigQuery.

Specifically, I have a question about the generated tables events_* and events_intraday_*.

I think events_intraday_* is automatically deleted when events_* is created.
Is it possible to set this so that it is not deleted?